# AWS CORS no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, get, cors

Im trying to send get request with JSON to AWS API gateway. This works fine from Postman, but when i try to send the same request using jquery i get error `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
Ive enabled CORS from AWS and set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a wildcard.
I followed this guide https://medium.com/@peorth/using-jquery-to-access-a-aws-api-gateway-cors-afa11fd27f2a and added `crossDomain: true` yet it changed nothing.
This is my jquery request:

```
var settings = {
        "url": "https://XXXX.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/function",
        "crossDomain": "true",
        "method": "GET",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Amz-Content-Sha256": "XXXXXXX",
            "X-Amz-Date": "20210201T172448Z",
            "Authorization": "XXXX, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXXXX"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({"key":"1","id":"TST","action":"singleLed","value":r+""+g+""+b}),
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Im all out of ideas. How could i get the API working or is there another way to post data to AWS without involving CORS?

Comment: '*Ive enabled CORS from AWS and set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a wildcard*' in this case you've not followed the guide correctly, or the URL you've enabled via CORS doesn't match the request originator. Enabling CORS on AWS is the correct solution to your issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could you clarify? When CORS is enabled AWS automatically sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a wildcard. According to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html that should be all thats needed. From the API gateway page i can see OPTIONS method with Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control, Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods. What am i missing?

Comment: You need to set the URL of your requesting domain in to `Allow-Origin`, and set the headers and methods as required in the other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.
When i enabled CORS from AWS it didnt actually add all the necessary headers to the integration response. Once i edited those header mappings and removed authentication in order to use wild card everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your request response matches the form:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "headers":{
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET"
    },
    "body":"success"
...
}
```